# Site URL always in front of other URLs

Tags: urls

My Wordpress site is having a bad URL structure when I'm adding new URL.

For example in comments, when commentators fill in their website, it always has this structure `http://mysite.com/www.commentorsite.com/`.
The same thing happens in my side bar widget. When I add new text widget and put something like this `<a href="facebook.com/mypage" title="Find Us On Facebook"><span class="social">Find Us on Facebook</span></a>`, the result showing this instead `http://mysite.com/facebook.com/mypage`.

Could anyone help me solve this please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start your links with `http://`

Examples:

1. The link `facebook.com/mypage` becomes `http://facebook.com/mypage`
2. The link `www.commentorsite.com/` becomes `http://www.commentorsite.com/`

This will stop the links becoming `http://mysite.com/www.commentorsite.com/` or `http://mysite.com/facebook.com/mypage`

Comment: Great! It's working. Thanks you very much +1!